# Using combobox as column header in javafx tableview

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-2, tableview

I am working with javafx2.2 and want to this thing don't know whether something already exist or not.

I need to add `combobox` to column header of a `tableview` but I want to retain functionality of clicking header and sort my data.

I know I can attach `combobox` using `TableColumn.setgraphic(ComboBox);` and use width of `combobox` and `tablecol` accordingly and have `combobox` on top of my column header but I don want this.

I want `combobox` to take complete space of my `columnheader` but with functionality of sorting on click.

Is it achievable? If yes then how?

Comment: click allows to sort, and to open a combobox - what is your choice?

Comment: I want to make somethng like this
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf

So can't I add combo box graphic a label (in some percentage of my header) and still have click based sorting

Comment: "Manufacturer" columns header looks like column.setGraphic(new VBox(new Label("Manufacturer"), new ComboBox(...)))...